# Apache2 access.log interpretation

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, log-files

I'm pretty new to apache in general. It's a LAMP installation on Ubuntu server 14.04 and all is up to date.

I'm also running a squid proxy on the same box(not transparent) with success in my LAN(defined traffic is caching and speeding to clients nicely). Apache is up and running just fine. I've got fail2ban installed and configured correctly, ModSecurity.

What I am curious about are following entries in access.log and what is actually going on:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014:18:34:25 -0400] "GET /st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=6169978& pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.1" 404 401 "http://www.activeinfogame.com/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)"
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014:18:34:28 -0400] "GET /st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=6169978& pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.1" 404 400 "blahblah" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 3.0.04506; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; InfoPath.2)"
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014:18:34:46 -0400] "GET /st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=2913570&p ub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.1" 404 401 "http://www.addnewgame.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1"
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Aug/2014:18:35:05 -0400] "GET /ttj?id=3008680&size=300x250 HTTP/1.1" 404 402 "blahblah/Games/Guns" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 4.0.20402; MS-RTC LM"
```

Here's some output for the firewall:

```
Aug 25 18:52:34 xxxxx kernel: [341528.004885] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=18942 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64955 DPT=80 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Aug 25 18:53:18 xxxxx kernel: [341571.975861] [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=24169 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64962 DPT=80 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

What is going on? These GETs are coming from `127.x.x.x`! Waa? Why??

Please let me know what more info you need. I'm subscribe instantly via email.

Thanks in advance, gents and ladies.

Comment: The gets are coming from 127.0.0.1 because you have a squid proxy running.  Squid is making the requests to apache.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you, yoonix.  This is indeed the default behaviour as I have my setup.  Now, to rid myself of ads.